# A method not executing in Asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, methods

I'm calling a method from the code behind file but for some reason it doesn't execute. This is the method :

```
 public string getMajorName(int value)
    {
        LibraryArticlesEntities la = new LibraryArticlesEntities();
    //    Label1.Text += "done";
        var majorname = la.Majors.Where(a => a.MajorID == value).Select(a => a.MajorName).SingleOrDefault();
        return majorname;

    }
```

And I'm calling it from here

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#getMajorName(Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["MajorID"]))%>'></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="label"></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try to change your label line to <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%=getMajorName(Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["MajorID"]))%>'></asp:Label>

Comment: difference is: # -> =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call page.databind in page load.